# Как правильно верстать баннер интернет магазина?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Для практики решил попробовать сверстать интернет магазин и столкнулся вроде бы с простой вещью, но я никак не могу понять, как будет правильнее сверстать баннеры в слайдере. Заметил что во многих интернет магазинах их даже не верстают, а просто вставляют как картинку. Правильно ли будет в этом случае так сделать? Или лучше все же сверстать текст, добавить фон и картинку справа (или может картинку вместе с фоном?)? Ссылка на макет https://www.figma.com/file/qMXkDhgcHGllFghkoFc3ST/5KVT-(Copy)?node-id=38%3A862

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от заказчика - вставлять просто картинку или полноценно верстать. Со своей точки зрения - правильнее полностью сверстать если вы все-таки для практики решили делать(опыт всегда пригодится)+плюс слайдер в баннере несложная задача